# Select random variables from list with limit Python

Tags: python, random, repeat

I need to generate unique random lists for 3 different objects, each object can appear once on each lis and each code has to in fixed length of 5.

```
import random 
#generate random codes
def generator(code, objects):
    

    for i in range(len(code)):
        x = random.choices(objects)
        code[i] = x[0]
        

#Check if code is unique
def isSame(code, list):
    if code not in list:
        return False
    else:
        return True

#If code is unique, append it to the codeList and increase counter by 1
codeCount = 0
def listAppend(code, list):
    if isSame(code,list) == True:
        print('This code is not unique')
    else:
        list.append(code)
        global codeCount
        codeCount += 1



if __name__ == '__main__':
    codeList = []
    desiredCount = 12
    
    while codeCount != desiredCount:
        code = [None]*5
        objects = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
        
        generator(code, objects)
        listAppend(code,codeList)
   
    print(codeList)
```

This gives me random unique lists but however I couldn't think of how to make each object appear only once in each unique list.

e.g. ['a', 'g', 'g', 'a', 'e'] ==> 'g' and 'a' has repeated twice where I need them to appear only once. like, ['a','b','c','d','e']

Can anyone think of a good way to do this? Thanks!!

---

**EDIT:** each code has to have fixed length of 5. Also I'm using random.choices to use its probability parameter.

Comment: Try using a `set`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do it is:

```
from random import randrange as rr
Alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
def generate(length):
    code=[]
    for _ in range(length):
         random_number=rr(0,len(Alphabet))
         if Alphabet[random_number]not in code:
             code.append(Alphabet[random_number])
    return code
```

This generates a random element from a tuple / list / string (in my case is a string of alphabet) and checks if the element is already in the code, and if not then it will be added to the code, the length of the code is determined by a parameter.

Comment: just edited the question, so sorry..each code has to have same length.

Comment: @erikci What do you mean by 'each code has to have the same length'?

Comment: ["a","g","g","a","e"] has length of 5, but after using set() its 3.

Comment: @erikci Ah got you, ill edit my post to correct to that

Answer (score 0):

This will generate all possible 3 unique element selections from the source.

```
import itertools
list(itertools.combinations('abcdefg',3))

[('a', 'b', 'c'),
 ('a', 'b', 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', 'e'),
 ('a', 'b', 'f'),
 ('a', 'b', 'g'),
 ('a', 'c', 'd'),
 ('a', 'c', 'e'),
 ('a', 'c', 'f'),
 ...
 ('d', 'f', 'g'),
 ('e', 'f', 'g')]
```

For size 5, it will be this list

```
 list(itertools.combinations('abcdefg',5))

[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
 ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f'),
 ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g'),
 ('a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f'),
 ('a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'g'),
 ('a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'g'),
 ('a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f'),
 ('a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'g'),
 ('a', 'b', 'd', 'f', 'g'),
 ('a', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'g'),
 ('a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'),
 ('a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'g'),
 ('a', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g'),
 ('a', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g'),
 ('a', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'),
 ('b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'),
 ('b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'g'),
 ('b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g'),
 ('b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g'),
 ('b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'),
 ('c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g')]
```

Comment: just edited the question, so sorry..each code has to have same length.

Comment: @erikci Yes, they have the same length of 3, that's what you initially indicated.  What length do you need?

Answer (score 0):

by only adding object.remove() line to function generator, I managed to get solution the way I wanted.

by removing whatever appended to the code list, reuse is eliminated.

```
#generate random codes
def generator(code, objects):
    

    for i in range(len(code)):
        x = random.choices(objects)
        code[i] = x[0]
        
        #new line
        objects.remove(x[0])
```